# Unable to start Elasticsearch on Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, elasticsearch

I remember using ES when I was on Mavericks, just a couple months ago and everything was fine. However, ever since the Java update (to 1.7) I've noticed some strange things.

I uninstalled ES and reinstalled it with brew. And it still doesn't start. Is there something I'm missing? I remember ES was as simple as brew install and it just works.

I even tried to start ES with bin/elasticsearch. But when I try to do `curl -X GET http://localhost:9200`, it says this `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused`

[image]

Comment: There should be a process using 9200. Elasticsearch seems to run correctly but log says "bound_address 127.0.0.1:9201", so, try to access localhost:9201

Comment: I did that. It says the same thing `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9201: Connection refused`. The WEIRD part is, when I try to access from the browser, it shows the JSON response and seems to be running.

Comment: I ended up doing 'sudo elasticsearch start'. It still says connection refused but somehow the search works. No clue how.

Answer (score -1):

Open file `/etc/hosts`

And comment this line

> fe80::1%lo0 localhost

Comment: can you please explain how/why this is supposed to help?